# How to switch off CMake automoc for subdirectories?

Tags: cmake, automoc

I have directory `aaa` and `aaa/bb`. I want CMake to create the `moc_compilation.o` file only for `aaa/*.cxx` files, but it scans recursively `aaa/bb/*.cxx` files also. How can I disable the recursive scan for automoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`SKIP_AUTOMOC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/SKIP_AUTOMOC.html#prop_sf:SKIP_AUTOMOC) source file property to skip automoc processing for one file, or an entire group of files. This works for header files as well:

```
file(GLOB MY_EXCLUDED_SOURCES aaa/bb/*.cxx)
set_property(SOURCE ${MY_EXCLUDED_SOURCES} PROPERTY SKIP_AUTOMOC ON)
```